# Session expires on open or refreshing new tab Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am using `codeigniter session` in my admin where each page is checking session is exist or not.

Now problem is when I am getting login and then `opening another tab` or `refreshing other tab` and then I am coming back to my admin panel and refreshing it. Its session gets expire and get logout.

Comment: you check your url and share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved there was same name of sess_cookie_name in config file of front-end and back-end of my site so when I was loading front-end the back-end    session conflict with front-end and get new front-end session id so back-end was get logout.

now I have changed both sess_cookie_name of both front-end and back-end so now it is working perfectly